# Excel - how to print a chart on a large sheet of paper

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am planning on sending a PDF file to a printer to print a large 13X9 inch page (PDF will have the same measurements). I have a table that I'd like to fully expand to fit that page with the correct resolution so that it doesn't print out pixelated.

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Ideally Excel would demarcate the 13X9 page on the file, allowing me to visually size things and layout it out appropriately.

Basically trying to avoid having to create a new Adobe file just to do a print layout when I literally have this table in Excel in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the table, the portion that you wish to print.
2. Find and use `define print area` in the Excel menus or ribbon
3. Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> hit <kbd>P</kbd> then select to print with `size
   fit to paper`.

*From memory, no Excel to check with at this location*

Comment: but unfortunately, the paper sizes are limited to what I can print from my computer... I kind of need to create an arbitrary size, because I'm printing to a PDF that I will send to a professional printer. what I really need is like... on any Adobe file you can specify exactly how big your page/canvas will be

Comment: You should be able to set the page size in (older) Excel > Page setup *(again, no Excel to check with)*.